# Delete part of entities using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, javafx

I have some problem to understand how to delete entities using Hibernate.

I have Table (Object1) with relations to other Tables (OneToMany) like: User, Localization, Status, Object2ID, Object3ID.

How to make Hiberante session.delete - delete Object1 and Object2 where ID=Obejct2ID (Object3 where ID =Object3ID) and do not delete User, Localization, Status relations - those values are constant and I used it only to attribute my Object. Here is my code (not all code but only definition with annotations):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OBJECT1")
public class Object1  {
    @Id
    @Column(name="ID_Object1") 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer idObject1;

    @ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_LOCALIZATION")
    private Localization LOCALIZATION;
```

And my localization class:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="LOCALIZATION")
public class Localization {
    @Id 
    @Column (name="ID_LOCALIZATION") 
    private int ID_LOCALIZATION;

    @Column (name="LOCALIZATION")
    private String Localization;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy="LOCALIZATION")
    private Set<Object1> OBJECT1;

    public Localization(){
    }

    public Localization(int ID_LOCALIZATION,String Localization){
        this.ID_LOCALIZATION= ID_LOCALIZATION;
        this.Localization= Localization;
    }
```

I can insert, update data but when I want to delete Object1, hibernate delete also data in child table.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please post the relevant mappings.

Comment: They are defined by annotations :)

Comment: so how I should change my annotation to give that functionality: Delete object1 didn't provide any change to Localization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate ORM will delete your entities relationship as you define them.
3 ways to delete an Entity with Hibernate... with a generic model entity named Object1 (User, or anything else Entity of your model) :

1# delete a transient object:

```
Object1 obj1 = new Object1();
obj1.setId(7);
session.delete(obj1);
```

2# delete a persistent object: with session.load(Class clazz, Long id)

```
Object1 obj1 = session.load(Object1.class, 7L);
if (null!=obj1) { session.delete(obj1); }
```

3# delete with Hibernate HQL:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("delete Object1 where id = :idObj");
query.setParameter("idObj", 7L);
int result = query.executeUpdate();
if (result > 0 ) {
   logger.info("The object with id#{} was removed from db.", 7L);
}
```

And for your question about relationships handled with Hibernate, search about the way of defining them with JPA Annotations, Hibernate Annotations way seems to be outdated (as far I know they are deprecated since some times).

```
javax.persistence.CascadeType
```

And this will certainly become something like that with your Entity :

```
@Entity(name = "USER") 
public class User {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private long userId;

   // others fields

   // relationships
   @OneToMany(optional=false,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, 
   mappedBy="user",targetEntity=Localization.class)
   private Localization localization;

   @OneToMany(optional=false,cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, 
   mappedBy="user",targetEntity=Status.class)
   private Status status;

   // etc.
}
```

This way you are sending a call to persist the relationships when you are storing a new User, and when you will need to delete an User, you will not delete the Localization or the Status entities.

A good article you can follow with some [jpa/hibernate best practises](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/)

To delete an object without deleting its own relationships, you must set the relationships inside your object to `null` before your delete operation.

```
// something like that with an initialized Object1 obj1 having some relationships
obj1.setLocalization(null);
// and now delete your object with the #2 or the #3 method I have given before... see what happens!
// i.e.
if (null!=obj1) { session.delete(obj1); }
```

Comment: ThierryB - could you please look at my first post. I gave my actual code

Comment: I think it is the way you make your delete operation which is not well done.
In order to delete one object which is linked with relationships, you must detach it from the object graph.

Comment: @see my edited answer, I think it will resolve your problem.
That's because you need to handle relationships links in java before any objects graph operations.

Comment: Great! I thought that hibernate can manage with that and detach automatically every relations before delete process. First steps using Hibernate - now that is clear for me! Thanks a lot!!